# Create series in charts + bind dynamically to datasource

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a DB holding a table "measurements" for measurement values of different locations like:

**Location_FK;Temperature;Timestamp;**

1;23.1;19/01/2018 12:12:12

1;23.7;19/01/2018 13:12:12

2;23.4;19/01/2018 06:23:12

2;23.2;19/01/2018 11:23:45

1;23.5;19/01/2018 07:45:00

2;23.9;19/01/2018 12:01:11

...
and a table "locationList" holding the location names:
**Location_ID;Location_Name;**

and new data is inserted at regular intervals (also new locations are added from time to time).

In an ASP.NET project I want to display a chart, holding multiple series, one series for each location. X-axis shall be "timestamp", y-axis shall be "temperature".

I created a SqlDataSource in my aspx file like
`<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQL_DataSource_DB" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConn %>" SelectCommand="select dbo.measurements.temperature, dbo.measurements.timestamp, dbo.locationlist.locationName from dbo.measurements`

My issue is: How do I bind my chart to this datasource properly, to have created one series for each location dynamically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Link 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203246/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072209-1.aspx)

Try above link it has complete description and full detail of microsoft charts.

[Link 2](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart)

Next link has many example for chart controls. Your question is broad so it is not possible to provide quick and handy code to copy paste. Read the tutorial and you will be able to develop many complex charts.

```
Using myConnection As New SqlConnection 
   myConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("NorthwindConnectionString").ConnectionString 

   Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand 
   myCommand.Connection = myConnection 
   myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT CategoryName, COUNT(*) as ProductCount FROM Products p INNER JOIN Categories c ON c.CategoryID = p.CategoryID GROUP BY CategoryName ORDER BY CategoryName" 

   myConnection.Open() 
   Dim myReader As SqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader() 

   chtCategoriesProductCount.DataBindTable(myReader, "CategoryName")

   myReader.Close() 
   myConnection.Close() 
End Using
```

The SQL query used returns a record for each category, where each record includes two columns: CategoryName, the name of the category; and ProductCount, the number of products associated with the category. As you can see, in the call to the DataBindTable method I've specified that the "CategoryName" column returned from the database should be used as the X value (thereby indicating that ProductCount should be the Y value.)

The DataBindTable adds a new series to the Chart control so you do not need to specifically define a series in the declarative markup. The DBChartData.aspx demo's declarative markup follows. Note that I've specified a title for the chart via the  collection.

```
<asp:Chart ID="chtCategoriesProductCount" runat="server"> 
   <Titles> 
      <asp:Title Text="Number of Products in Categories"></asp:Title> 
   </Titles> 

   <ChartAreas> 
      <asp:ChartArea Name="MainChartArea"> 
      </asp:ChartArea> 
   </ChartAreas> 
</asp:Chart>
```